# Formset is_valid returns False without any changes

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm pretty new to this so bear with me. 
I've created an 'Edit Book' form using `modelformset_factory` to build the form with the Book model. When I load the form with data from the model and try to save it, regardless of whether I change the data in the form in anyway `is_valid()` always returns False.

Code:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_reading = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_read = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    reading = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    book_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from models import Book

def edit_book(request, book_id):
    BookFormSet = modelformset_factory(Book, exclude=('user', 'date_reading', 'date_read', 'reading', 'book_read'), max_num=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = BookFormSet(queryset=Book.objects.filter(pk=book_id))
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

            return redirect('/books/' + str(book_id))
        else:
            formset = BookFormSet(queryset=Book.objects.filter(pk=book_id))
            return render(request, 'books/edit.html', {'formset':formset})
```

**Additional notes:**

formset.is_bound returns False
formset.errors returns []
formset.non_form_errors() doesn't return anything
formset.has_changed() returns True

Comment: stacktrace? did you include {{ formset.management_form }} in your template?

Comment: I hadn't earlier. But I just added it and is_valid still returns false.

Comment: Mark, I think the else was scoped under the outmost if, not the inner one. "I think" as it makes sense to have a view that does something outside that if-post, other than just dying silently

Comment: I don't see you are passing the POST data into the formset prior to validation check

Comment: Mark, the else was scoped under the outmost if. With this edit it throws an error.

Comment: Aamir, since the form is instantiated using data from the model, shouldn't that be passed in to the validation check?

Comment: Aamir, nevermind. That was the problem, thanks!!

Comment: I had similar issue with a derived Form, which internally gathered data from request.POST.  It appears formset strictly requires the 'data' arg to be supplied.  Also encountered similar strictness with the 'initial' arg during a GET. (Django 2.2.3)